# Bourbon accordion click once expand/collapse when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, bourbon

Hello I'm new here and I wondered if anyone could help. I have implemented bourbon.io's accordion, but I can not get it to open and collapse on a single click.

It opens, but then stays open.

```
$('.js-accordion-trigger').bind('click', function(e){
  jQuery(this).parent().find('.submenu').slideToggle('fast');  // apply the toggle to the ul
  jQuery(this).parent().toggleClass('is-expanded');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/antonymoss/9arurp28/)

Comment: How do you actually want it to behave.

Comment: When another section is clicked then the one that's opened will collapse. At the minute it stays opened.

Comment: just posted an answer for you @Antony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below if that is what you wanted

```js
$('.js-accordion-trigger').on('click', function(e) {
  $('ul.submenu').not($(this).parent().find('ul.submenu')).slideUp('fast');
  $(this).parent().find('.submenu').toggleClass('is-expanded').slideToggle('fast');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
ul.submenu {
  display: none;
}

.is-expanded {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="accordion">
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-accordion-trigger">Accordion Item</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="js-accordion-trigger">Another Item</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)">Sub Item 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Is there a parenthesis missing from line two? I cant get it to work.

Comment: sorry that was a typo while removing `console.log` statement check code now @AntonyMoss just updated the answer

Comment: No I wanted the effect in this example https://codepen.io/danhearn/pen/vWXzvm?limit=all&page=2&q=accordion+js

Comment: Apologies as I am a new developer.

Comment: i cant find any difference other than we are using `slideToggle` and the code you provided uses class to show/hide, do you want it not to `slide` but simply `show` and `hide` without slide efffect?

Comment: If you notice in the codepen example, only one section is displayed at any one time. The version you have done displays all sections until you click again.

Comment: check now @AntonyMoss just updated the snippet, i still used the `slide` effect you can swap it with any effect you wan t

Comment: – absolute genius, that's exactly how I wanted it. Thank you. Ive update the JSFiddle

Comment: glad that i could help you out , do select the answer as correct so other can benefit too having same problem